# Converting Javascript Date

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date String in this format: `Tue Sep 02 00:00:00 GMT+200 2014`, I'd like to have only in Javascript this ISO Format: `2014-09-02T00:00:00.000Z`.

So I have wrote this code:

```
var date = new Date("Tue Sep 02 00:00:00 GMT+200 2014");
date.toJSON();
```

but it returns: `"2014-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"`.
How can I have the right date in ISO format? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you expect that `Tue Sep 02 00:00:00 GMT+200 2014`  should equal `2014-09-02T00:00:00.000Z` ?  The first date has a time offset that is not present in the second one.

Comment: "Tue Sep 02 00:00:00 GMT+200 2014" comes from java code, it is passed to Javascript, but in JS I need the same datetime in ISO Format, it is possible?

Comment: @django: We are telling you that you already *are* getting the correct ISO format output.

Comment: Thank u very much to all. Ok it's all clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the JavaScript native Date Object, you may want to look at [its documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) first, especially the [`toISOString()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString).

```
var date = new Date("Tue Sep 02 00:00:00 GMT+200 2014");
var n = date.toISOString();
```

this returns:

```
n: '2014-09-01T22:00:00.000Z'
```

which is the right ISO format. Your initial time is **GMT+2** so, in ISO time, it corresponds to the same date/time but two hours *before*. As it is the 2nd of Sept, 00:00:00, 2 hours before lead to the day before, the 1st of Sept, at 22:00:00. You can't have the `2014-09-02T00:00:00.000Z` you want in your question because it is not corresponding to an ISO date.

You can read more about [ISO 8601 on Wikipedia](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/ISO_8601).

Comment: I'm gonna edit my links tho :) As they are saying the same thing (for this time), I thought it would have been OKish to do so. I'm editing this. Thanks for pointing this out @t.niese !

Comment: w3schools got better, but they are still partial incomplete, and still have misleading examples and descriptions. e.g. for the Date object the: `[...]Note that JavaScript Date objects can only be instantiated by calling JavaScript Date as a constructor[...]` is an important information, that is missing.

Answer (score -1):

There is a method for that.

```
date.toISOString()
```

Comment: It returns also : "2014-09-01T22:00:00.000Z".

Comment: `date.toISOString()` returns the same as [`MDN: Date.prototype.toJSON()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON) `[...]Calling toJSON() returns a JSON formatted string (using toISOString) representing the Date object's value.[...]`

Comment: Because that is the representation of that date in ISO format, note that you are using GMT+2 and ISO use Zulu

Comment: Anybody know how to do it in JS?